# Get Github URL for tag SHA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano

With a Rails Capistrano deploy, if you deploy from git you get a REVISION file in your deployment. It's a SHA of the object deployed.

I have a bit of admin-only code that links to:
`https://github.com/<company>/<project>/commit/<sha>`

That way devs can easily double check the details of the current deployment. It worked and was useful.

I recently changed our deployment system from branch-based deployment to (annotated)-tag-based deployment.

Now the REVISION contains a SHA for the tag.

I cannot figure out how to generate a URL to GitHub with this SHA.

`https://github.com/<company>/<project>/tree/<tag>` works, but `https://github.com/<company>/<project>/tree/<tag-sha>` doesn't.

Attempts to resolve this with the API failed as well.

So given a tag-SHA, how do I generate the GitHub URL for it?

Comment: Why not save the commit hash that the tag points to instead of hashing the tag? I assume you are doing `sha256sum("v0.1.0")` ? I guess you could run a cron job that continually does `git fetch --tags; git tag` and manually store a hash table of what hashes refer to what tag...

Comment: Is the following what you're looking for: `https://github.com/<company>/<project>/commit/<tag-sha>`?

Comment: @Plato I do a `git tag -a tagname`. In capistrano, I set the object to deploy via `set :branch, tagname`. It deploys what I want exactly. The REVISION file that ends up getting generated has a SHA, not a tagname. If I `git describe the_revision_sha` it spits out the tag name. So it's all done for me. If github is incapable of doing something useful with a SHA in git, then I'll have to figure something else out I guess. (I did ask github support and am still waiting to hear back.)

Comment: Great, @DavePowers answer (and your original approach) should be correct then

Comment: @Plato It must be a github bug then. Because it doesn't work. I'll leave this question open until I hear from them, and answer with relevant details.

Comment: are you sure you pushed the commit? for example here is a [tag page](https://github.com/caolan/async/releases/tag/v1.4.0) and here is the [commit page](https://github.com/caolan/async/commit/5bfcd31c72e003f96df025e75753463da61f49f9) for the tagged commit

Comment: The tag is pushed. The commit is pushed. I can get it via a `trees/tag_name` or `commit/commit_sha` but not `trees/tag_sha`. That is the thing that is unusable, but the thing I need to use. Strange that there are URLs and APIs that can use a commit sha, a tag, but not a tag sha.

Comment: a tag sha IS a commit sha, what do you need that's different from `commit/commit_sha`?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've posted the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capistrano deployment from git generates a short SHA.
see https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/bfc4a82359251b8fd28165fc0d981c7f8f0baf99/lib/capistrano/git.rb#L43

Github's API requires a full SHA.

That is the problem.

I've opened an issue asking not to shorten SHAs (unless there is a valid reason against this request). https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1468